# operator overloading outside of a class!

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-overloading, definition

when i was trying to seperate the declaration and implementation of a non-member overloaded operator, i got a LNK2001 error in VC2010, my code was like this:

-foo.h-

```
class A
{
public:
    A(float x);
    float x;
};
A operator +(const A&, const A&);
```

-foo.cpp-

```
A::A(float x)
{
    this->x = x;
}

A operator +(const A& lh, const A& rh)
{
    return A(lh.x + rh.x);
}
```

so once i use the '+' operation, the error pumps out, but if i remove the declaration in the header file, there are no LNK2001 errors.. i cannot figure out why..

Comment: Are you using any namespaces?

Comment: yes, i used a my own defined namespace

Comment: next time give the exact error message.  But the namespace is creating the problem.  See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you have the definition in a different namespace than the declaration.  ADL is finding the declaration (since it's in the same namespace as the class), and then you get an unresolved external error during link.

e.g.

-foo.h-

```
namespace aspace
{
  class A
  {
  public:
      A(float x);
      float x;
  };
  A operator +(const A&, const A&);
}
```

-foo.cpp-

```
#include "foo.h"
using namespace aspace;

A::A(float x)
{
    this->x = x;
}

A operator +(const A& lh, const A& rh)
{
    return A(lh.x + rh.x);
}
```

Will give the error you describe.  The solution is to put the `operator+` definition in the correct namespace:

```
namespace aspace
{
  A operator +(const A& lh, const A& rh)
  {
      return A(lh.x + rh.x);
  }
}
```

Comment: hi Ben, this is exactly as you said, i got it right now, thank you very much!!

Comment: @Alan: Since you're new to this site, you may not have noticed that just to the left of my answer is a gray outline of a checkmark.  If you click that it will make my answer "accepted" which gives me points and lets anyone else with this question know that it is the right answer.  You should also "accept" the correct answer on your other question.

Comment: @Alan: as a general rule, banish `using namespace` from your toolbox. I know many books / tutorials use it, but it brings more trouble than it's worth. Consider namespace aliasing instead if it's really too unwieldy.

Comment: @Matthieu: `using namespace` is big trouble inside header files, but is perfectly alright in implementation files and inside functions.

Comment: @Ben: you just answered a question where it posed an issue :) I don't see much gain with this directive, you can either use namespace aliasing or using a function.

Comment: @Matthieu: I disagree.  `using namespace` wasn't the solution to the problem, but it didn't cause the problem either.  The problem was declaring`operator=` in one namespace and defining it in another.  `using namespace` didn't play any role in that.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Ah sorry, since the namespaces didn't appeared in the OP's question I misunderstood the issue. I'll still refrain to use `using namespace` though :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with the code you have presented.

Are you sure that this is exactly the code you have?

If it is, then it seems the only explanation is that you have somehow managed to not have [foo.cpp] in your Visual Studio project, assuming you're using Visual Studio.

If using command line tools, the corresponding thing would be not including [foo.obj].

If those comments don't help, can you create a single file small program that exhibits the problem?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Change your prototype to (if you insist on keeping the definition of operator+ in the enclosing namespace for whatever reason)

```
A aspace::operator +(const A& lh, const A& rh)
```