# non-member operator == can i make it static?

Tags: c++

I wrote a non-member operator == function in this style at first in the header file:

```
bool operator==(
  const Node& lhs,
  const Node& rhs)
{
  return lhs.uid == rhs.uid;
}
```

but it compiled fail for the reason that multiple definition of it.
I try two methods, they both work.
1 move the implemetation to cpp file
2 make this operator == static function.

Most of the search result talk about the first solution.
But Can I make it static? which one is better?

Thanks in advance~

Comment: When you say multiple definitions, are there other instances of this function in the code?  Can you post them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [operator overloading outside of a class!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121125/operator-overloading-outside-of-a-class)

Comment: I included this header in other source files

Answer (score 4):

If you've put the function in the header file you need to make it `inline`. Otherwise the compiler will spit out a separate copy of it in any source file that uses it, leading to linker clashes.

```
inline bool operator==(
  const Node& lhs,
  const Node& rhs)
{
  return lhs.uid == rhs.uid;
}
```

Comment: Inline is better anyway for a trivial implementation such as this, especially if you expect that function to be called often (such as when sorting a container).